# How do you normalize values to 0-3?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normalization

I'm aware of course of how you normalize values by using this formula (value-min)/(max-min) and that will give you a range from +1 to 0 but my question is how do you take a value from +100 to -100 range and normalize them to 0-3 instead?

Comment: The formula will normalize it to [0, 1].

Comment: @user2974951 I edited my answer to correct that but I'm still unsure how to normalize a value from a +100 to -100 range and convert it to a 0 to 3 range

Comment: Use the formula to normalize it into the range [0, 1]. Once you have your data in the [0, 1] range, can you see a way to transform it into [0, 3]?

Comment: The only challenge I could see is if the data range is not limited and could be anything in -Inf to +Inf. In that case, 3*sigmoid(x) could be an option.